# How do I determine if the executing assembly is a web app or winform/console?

Tags: .net, asp.net, c#-4.0

I would like to write a helper function which build the exception message to write to a log.
The code look like:

if(IsWebApp)
{
        use HttpContext to get the Request Path and RawUrl
}
else
{
        //else it a winform/console
         Use Assembly to get executing path.
 
}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [HttpRuntime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.aspx) class:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath))
    //ASP.Net
else 
    //Non-ASP.Net
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out to the rest of us that not everything in asp.net is a request thread - learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 1):

Just check for some object that only exists in a web application, like `HttpRuntime.AppVirtualPath` that SLaks suggested.

If it's a web application, you would still want to check if `HttpContext.Current` is null. If the exception occurs in code that is not run beacuse of a request, it doesn't have any context. The Session_OnEnd event for example runs when a server session is removed, so it doesn't have the context.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if HttpContext.Current != null.

Comment: Wrong.  This will be null in a non-request thread inside an ASP.Net AppDomain.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
If (Not System.Web.HttpContext.Current Is Nothing) Then

End If
```

or

```
if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null){

}
```

Comment: Wrong.  This will be null in a non-request thread inside an ASP.Net AppDomain.  Also, VB.Net has an `IsNot` keyword.  Finally, he's using C#.

Comment: Never have so many been so wrong in so short a period of time! Thanks for setting us straight.
I've been been programming in VB since VB5 so sometimes old habits die hard.
That's why I included both.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [DomainManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.domainmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type of Current AppDomain. [MSDN documentation of AppDomainManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public static class AspContext
{
    public static bool IsAspNet()
    {
        var appDomainManager = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainManager;
        return appDomainManager != null && appDomainManager.GetType().Name.Contains("AspNetAppDomainManager");
    }
}
```

You can also check [this other answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464979/determine-whether-running-in-asp-net-or-winforms-console-without-system-web/33172055#33172055)